# Checking in which column a value exists using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new with pandas.
I have 2 datasets, the first one looks like this:

```
Timestamp_info    Id_info
2019-11-25        2
2019-11-25        3
2019-11-25        4
2019-11-25        5
2019-11-25        10
```

The second one looks like this:

```
Date                         Click_id
2019-11-25 00:00:06+00:00    1
2019-11-25 00:00:06+00:00    2
2019-11-25 00:00:06+00:00    4
2019-11-25 00:00:06+00:00    5
2019-11-25 00:00:06+00:00    7
```

I am trying to output a .CSV file which would have the following structure:

```
Timestamp    Id    Exists in the first file   Exists in the second file
2019-11-25   1     False                      True  
2019-11-25   2     True                       True  
2019-11-25   3     True                       False
2019-11-25   4     True                       True
2019-11-25   10    True                       False
...
```

How I imagine going forward with this problem is to merge two files into one, then I would have the full list of both Timestamp and Id

```
df_one = first_file
df_two = second_file
full_file = pd.concat(df_one,df_two,axis=1)
```

But the files get joined not the way I want to:

```
Timestamp_info  Id_info  Date                         Click_id
2019-11-25      5
                         2019-11-25 00:00:06+00:00    10
```

From here on forward I do not know how I would proceed with correctly merging the files and checking in which file the id exists and adding TRUE or FALSE value in a column.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Refer [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my own, here is the answer:

Renaming both datafiles so that they have the same column names:

```
renamed_one = df_one.rename(columns={'Timestamp_info':'Date','Id_info':'Id'})
renamed_two = df_one.rename(columns={'Date':'Date','Click_Id':'Id'})
frames = [renamed_one,renamed_two]
result = pd.concat(frames)
result['In the first file'] = result['Id'].isin(renamed_one['Id'])
result['In the second file'] = result['Id'].isin(renamed_two['Id'])
export = result.to_csv('Final export', encoding='utf-8', index = False)
```